# Управление мышью средствами vbs

Tags: dll, exe, vbscript

Кода нет. Нашел управление нажатия правой кнопки мыши

```
set shell = createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.run "rundll32.exe user32.dll, mouse_event 1", 1, true
```

Как можно переместить курсор через стандартные библиотеки Windows 7 через vbs?

В интернете я нашел много способов через разные языки программирования, но мне нужно используя штатные средства. Через C# можно user32.dll использовать, но можно ли как то обойтись без C# тоже используя user32.dll?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807543/windows-command-script-that-moves-mouse-cursor-n-pixels/53769159

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev Не совсем понятно. Как можно использовать `rundll32 user32.dll,SetCursorPos`
В mouse.bat используется стороннее приложение

Comment: В интернете я нашел много способов через разные языки программирования, но мне нужно используя штатные средства. Через C# можно user32.dll использовать, но можно ли как то обойтись без C# тоже используя user32.dll?

Comment: Максим, я бы не стал избегать средств C#. Дело в том, что .Net Framework v.2 и v.3.5 входят в состав Windows 7 (Pro). Код, которые позволяет, используя System.Windows.Forms, работать с курсором мыши занимает буквально пару строк. Скомпилировать этот код можно используя **любую** версию **Visual C# Command Line Compiler** (не ниже v. 2) в составе .net Framework. А скомпилированный в 4КБ exe-файл можно использовать как душа пожелает. Ещё раз - код подойдет к любой версии нет_фреймворк